# i'm trying to remove a line from a text box but don't know the exact line

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm adding a line to a text box when an check box is clicked.  what should i do when the check box is un clicked and want to remove the item:

```
Private Sub cbAddress_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbAddress.SelectedValueChanged
if cbAddress.checked = true then
    dim thetext as string = txtTextbox.text
    dim theItem as string = "test"
    txtTextbox.text = thetext & Environment.NewLine & theItem
else
    ' i'm try to delete the line.
   ' I've tried to txtTextbox.text.Remove(blah, blah)
end if
```

should i track which line it is added to in the text box to delete it when unchecked, or is there a better way?

Comment: Is the text in the textbox editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method:

```
Private Sub cbAddress_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbAddress.CheckedChanged
    Dim theItem As String = "test"
    If cbAddress.Checked = True Then
        Dim thetext As String = txtTextbox.Text
        txtTextbox.Text = thetext & Environment.NewLine & theItem
    Else
        txtTextbox.Text = txtTextbox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine & theItem, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Environment.NewLine`

```
txtTextbox.Text = txtTextbox.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
```

Comment: it might be unchecked after other things are checked off.

Comment: please use the above line for your respective condition. I don't know your implementation logic.